# Any example on how to use redis-mock

Tags: node.js

I am looking at the  [redis-mock git repo](https://github.com/yeahoffline/redis-mock)  and I cannot see any example on how to proceed. Can some one help me to give some examples to begin so that I can take it forward. Thanks.

Comment: According to the README, the majority of instructions are not yet implemented; although it sounds useful this library is not ready for general use yet.

Comment: Thanks Elliot. How about fakeredis. I saw lot of people are using this but there are no update for a long.

Comment: https://github.com/hdachev/fakeredis ? Looks worth trying but with no maintainer, YMMV.  If you can't get it working, you may be forced to use a more basic "mock all and check call args" approach.  (Actually, in my opinion, that's the _best_ approach for simple get/set operations; starts becoming a real pain to unit test if you have complex series of Redis instructions, though.)

Comment: It would be nice to have a robust mock library for Redis for node, like Ruby has, but it appears that might be something missing from the ecosystem today.

Comment: Really appreciate your comments. Thanks Elliot